# What are a good No OP operation for vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, no-op

Something we can just put break point on while making sure it doesn't do anything else.

In c, that would be while(false);

What to do in vb.net?

Comment: something like while(false) in c

Comment: How placing a breakpoint on an artificial no-op statement is different from placing a breakpoint on any other statement?

Comment: Just place the breakpoint on the statement after the one you don't want anything to execute after.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you always need it to break there you can put 
`Stop` or `Debugger.Break()`

Comment: I want to unbreak easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a No-Op for some reason *(could this turn into a contest for the most ineffectual single line of code?!)*, how about these?

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)` - 1ms is unlikely to have a huge impact outside of a loop

`Debug.Write("")` - doesn't appear to output anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is a legitimate use-case for this.
When a temporary breakpoint is required after the statement of interest and this is the last line inside an if statement, an extra no-op type statement is required to place the temporary breakpoint on.
In this case I use:

```
If someCondition >0 Then

    doSomething
    Space (1)    'Dummy line to place breakpoint
End If
```

This returns a string containing one space, but does not assign it to anything. I use it in VBA, but it's also supported in .net

Answer (score 2):

My two cents...

You can combine any series of commands onto one line with colons:

```
If False Then : End If
Select Case False : Case Else : End Select
```

I've also made it into a sub. Then it gets a recognizable name of own:

```
'Definition...
Public Sub noop () 'Or Private, Protected, etc.
End Sub

'Usage...
Sub Main()
    If sometest Then
        noop
    Else
        MsgBox "test is false"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Very strange question, you could place a BreakPoint about anywhere in the code. But here are some useless lines :

```
 Do While False
 Loop

 While False
 End While
```

Even the following :

```
 Dim hello = Nothing
```

Or this :

```
 Format("", "")
```

Comment: can you do it in one line?

Comment: @JimThio How about the second suggestion?

Comment: `Dim hello As Object = Nothing` should work without an actual memory assignment; just an extra local on the stack.

Comment: No `Dim hello = Nothing` is not allowed; it doesn't know what type to give to `hello`.

Comment: @MarkHurd No it's fine. If you do this the compiler would assume its an object.

Comment: No, I tested it. It fails.

Comment: @MarkHurd that happens when [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) is set to off while [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) is On.

Comment: Sorry, I was caught by the LINQPad syntax checker acting differently to the actual compiler. I'm sure it previously broke as a compiler error, but it is now compiling fine and just showing as a red squiggle underline...

Answer (score 1):

A no-op statement is also useful as an aid to document code nicely and make it more easily understandable.  You could for example put in a statement like A = A.

For example:

If MyNumber => 100 then A = A
Else:

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old query, but for what it is worth, my preferred solution to the original question is
`Debug.Assert (vbTrue)`

If you wanted, you could use a variable instead of vbTrue and then enable/disable all breakpoints in your code by changing one variable

```
Dim bDisableBreakpoints as Boolean: bDisableBreakpoints = vbTrue
'your code here
Debug.Assert (bDisableBreakpoints)
'rest of your code
```

Simply change bDisableBreakpoints to `vbFalse` and the breakpoints will be set wherever you have used Debug.Assert

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is

```
dim b=1
```

Then I put a breakpoint there.